# Error when creating android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new in Android Developer and i learning. But when i create a new project, this error shown.

[image]

and in the error log i have so much error, and i don't know how can i export all of them here.
And In the project explorer, my project shown like this:

[image]

I don"t know how can i fix all of this error! Thanks for helping and sorry for my bad english!

**UPDATE:**

My problem is solved. The problem is from my appcompat-v7 project. My friends give me another link of this project and then try it again, and the problem is solved!
And tnx to all of you for your answers. :)

Comment: if you didnt learn the basic android development, i suggest you dont use library

Comment: try the following steps,i am not sure but It may resolve your issue. Right click on your project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are the steps:

1. Paste the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` that you have downloaded in `libs` folder of your project.
2. Right click on your project, select `Build Path` -> `Configure build path`.
3. Select `Library Tab` then `Add Jar` option and browse your recently added `v7` jar and click `OK`

[image]

that's it :)

## Update :

[image]

see here

[image]

Comment: I copied v7.jar into libs folder of my project. But when i click add jar. I can't find v7.jar, only v4.jar was there!

Comment: `appcompat-v7` is not a JAR. It is an Android library project. You have to import the `android-support-v7-appcompat` project into your workspace. Location  `<sdk>/extras/android/support/` directory.

Comment: How can i import? In the project properties>android>library. Appcompact v7 is marked with green check. Is that mean appcompact-v7 is imported?

Comment: @HosseinDibapour I have updated my answer take a look into it.

Comment: Thanks. I look at it. My library section of my project is the same as yours. Appcompat-v7 is checked green.

Comment: Not yet . I'm confused... :(

Comment: @HosseinDibapour Check the `Order-and-Export` tab all jar should be checked. Then clean your project.

Comment: I check that. Android dependencies has a red cross on it. And android 4.0 not checked.

Comment: I don't have android.jar ..... , and android dependencies has a red cross on it. The others same as yours.

Comment: @HosseinDibapour add it from `sdk\platforms\android-10\android.jar` location

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with your external library.

- Go to project properties by right clicking on project.
- Select android from left menu.
- check for the appcompat library in bottom window.

If it is not there, add it from a valid path. Clean the project and run it again.

Comment: It was there and also checked with green check. But my problem not solve.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the HDArtworks project.

Go to **Properties>>Android**
Then in the Library section: If you find a red cross in AppCompat_v7 then Select and remove it.

*Then click ok. Now come back to the Solution explorer and select the Appcompat_v7 project. and do the clean and build.*

When the appcompat_v7 project error free then again Right Click on the HDArtworks project. Go to **Properties>>Android**
Then in the Library section: If you find a red cross in AppCompat_v7 then Select and remove it. and click Add select AppCompat_v7 and click OK.

Now Clean and Build the HDArtwork project. It should solve the problem

Comment: Appcompact-v7 is marked with green check. And how can i do clean and build. This is my first project. And even i don't know why appcompact-v7 is added to my project. Because last year i create a project for test and appcompact-v7 not shown.

Comment: If Appcompact-v7 is marked with green check then you are almost there.

Just Make sure the appcompat_v7 Project is Error-free. Then just Clean your project and build again.

Comment: Appcompat-v7 still is not error-free. Little red cross on it. I check it and i see the error is come from this path: appcompat-v7>res>value-v21>styles-base.xml... this file has red cross on it.

Comment: I think finally you have reached to the main issue:
The only thing you have to do is to open the project.properties file of the android-support-v7-appcompat and change the target from target=android-19 to target=android-21.
Afterwards just do a Project --> Clean... so that the changes take effect.

Comment: Sorry where is the android-support-v7-appcompat?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, appcompat_v7 and android-support-v7-appcompat are same thing.. So do it for appcompat_v7 project. Find the project.properties file and do the modification as given in the last comment

Comment: I find it and i change the target. But when i click clean... the problem not fix :( the default target was android-14 and when i change that to 21 and clean... the problem not fix and BuildConfig.java in gen>android.support.v7.appcompat show a red cross of it.

Comment: You can try out a last thing:
Right click on the appcompat_v7  go to property. Select android. Now change the Project Buld target to different on rather than selected one. Now clean and build again.

Comment: I try that and still same issue. :( do you think if i install ADT Bundle my problem fix?

Answer (score 0):

Offline Method :

**1.**

or maybe you need Offline added this package.Download with Below Link :

> ```
> http://downloads.puresoftware.org/files/android/extras/support.zip
> ```

extract this in `SDK-root Folder/extras/android` something like that in Windows : ( for me )

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android
```

well, goto `Eclipse` and add this in your project by below method :

`Right Click` on your project `Properties > Android`, 
after Restart, it worked fine.

**2.**
also, you can Copy this Folder (***appcompat***) ;

*//you can find it with this Address :*

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat
```

or after Added above Download link, now ;
copy this Folder (appcompat) to Workspace and added with `Properties > Android` to your project.

Comment: you are using Windows Or Linux ? do you try Run As administrator then cleaned up and setup again this package? this is work, i promiss ; )

Comment: Thanks for answer. But still no chance. My appcompat-v7 library is added to my projects. I think the problem is from appcompat project, res>build-v21>style-base.xml here is the console error when i clean the project. http://paste.ubuntu.com/10629707/

Comment: most of the time with `Restart` `eclipse` these error's fix.also, try to run the project and make sure Fixed other error except these.

Comment: Still same errors :( I can't believe still no one can solve my problem. :(

Comment: i solved this problem today again, if you have come to chat or give me id or other something for fix this bug , dont worry.: ]