# Is android studio good for beginners?

Tags: android, android-studio

I start learning android developing with android studio. And with lynda.com tutorial called android studio first look. I try to install eclipse but i have so much errors in my projects with libraries. So my question is, is android studio good for beginners?

Comment: And like what errors? Is it interfering with other packages? I like Android Studio better than the "old" ADT IDE.

Comment: considering Eclipse and ADT are no longer supported by Google, Android Studio is what you want to use.

Comment: Android Studio is by far the best IDE for Android development. Eclipse is a treacherous highway filled with potholes, marauders and hitchhiking murderers. In comparison, Android Studio is like that quaint little stretch down by the nice little restaurant you always went to with your parents as a kid. It brings back fond memories every time you open it.

Comment: Except for that creepy Gradle guy who hides out in the alley behind the restaurant.

Comment: @AustinHanson Sadly, all the intro books I can find on Android Development are written for Eclipse. I was going to start playing with Android this weekend, but now I either get to choose good books or a good IDE.

Comment: @DaveS If you'd dig a little bit in Gradle's functionality, you'll appreciate it.

Comment: Hey I never said Gradle wasn't useful, still creepy.

Comment: @theJollySin I'd suggest Android Studio tutorials online to get familiarized with the IDE itself. Afterwards, grab the Big Nerd Guide or some other Android book for actual Android content.

Comment: Thanks all for answers. So i continue learning android studio. And i ask my problem with eclispe here and there is no solution. Anyway I'm done with eclipse:-)    http://stackoverflow.com/q/29093199/4679406

Comment: Another thing, is that native development in Android Studio is very painful yet. If you are up to NDK (games, OpenGL, OpenCV etc.) you'd better stick with another thing or combine several environments. For Java-related stuff Android Studio is a sweet candy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse was a main Android IDE, so many tutorial have written using it. But later, Google announced Android Studio, and it have been in beta version for a long time. But at current moment - Android Studio is one and only official IDE for Android, so if you are a beginner, it's a better for you to start using it, so later, you don't need to migrate your apps and projects from other IDE's. Also, Eclipse are no longer supported, so you should use Android Studio anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, but it isn't equals eclipse, so you'll have studying a little more. Every start is the same, but carry on is the key. Prepare to pass many hours without sleep. hahaha

Hugs!

Comment: Thanks, and i prepare myself for hours without sleep:-) i know eclipse is a amazing android developer app. But i always like be update and do jobs with recommendations... :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer** : No

Android Studio suggested by Google, but for you @**Hossein Dibapour** its better use and Programming with `Eclipse` Or `IntelliJ IDEA`.

**for many Reasons** :

with `Eclipse` and `IntelliJ IDEA` you can learn easy for `Base` then, you can use Android Studio after you acquaintance with those.

and also, for you, `Android Studio` is hard for Add And Edit some Codes or work with Gradle's.
regards.

Comment: Thanks mohsen. But i have a lot of problems with eclipse. Like this link: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29093199/4679406

Comment: well :] : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29153628/4409113